# Windows 10 start button not working despite Windows Explorer restart

Tags: windows-10

My windows 10 start button is not working despite restarting 'Windows Explorer' in Task Manager.

See a video here https://streamable.com/ajm7xg

Any solution or will I have to reinstall Windows 10?

Comment: Try DISM / SFC and let us know after restarting .    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John I've run all the cmd prompts and restarted. Still having the start button problem unfortunately.

Comment: @egg - What was the outcome of those commands.  After running them did those commands repair your installation?  What were the outputs of those commands?  Before you reinstall Windows, repairing any potential corruption, does the describe behavior happen while in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have run DISM and that has not fixed your issue, then there are two options left.

**(1) Run a Windows 10 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything

A Keep Everything Repair often works. If not,

**(2) Reinstall Windows 10.**

Failure of (1) could mean more serious Operating System damage,OR, a damaged Windows User Profile.

Either way, the best solution will be to back everything up and do a fresh install of Windows 10.  Restore data and install your applications